# Printing a right-aligned "#" staircase

Tags: c, printf

I am doing the following question in Hackerrank:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Basically, the code has to print out a right-aligned "staircase" made of "#" characters. So, if the input is 6, then the output is:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

This is the solution (in C) I have come up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int n,i; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char str[]="";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        strcat(str,"#");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n",n,i+1,str);
    return 0;
}
```

But this is not working and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I am ***not looking for a new solution***. I just want to know what my code is doing wrong.

TIA!

Comment: Please read the [documentation for `strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat). You need enough buffer space in your destination.

Comment: You have to allocate enough memory to *str* to hold the *#*

Comment: *I am not looking for a new solution.* -- Depends on what you mean by "new solution".  Having to allocate space might as well be a "new solution", as the code to do that may look much different than what you originally wrote.

Comment: *"this is not working"*: You should really elaborate.  Does it compile? Does it run? Does it segfault, or produce incorrect output?  There are a million variations of *"not working"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[]="";
```

You did not specify the length of `str`.
Do something like

```
  char str[10]="";//where 10 is the safest number you think.You should
                  //not have more than 10 characters.
```

Comment: You were right! It worked. I will spend the next 2 hours getting depressed over the fact that I made such a stupid mistake.
But, is there a way in C to create a string without specifying the size?

Comment: In C you always have to specify the size.

Comment: One more thing. When I ran the code, it had printed the first line correctly. The code messed up starting from the second line. That is why I didn't think it was a problem with the array length allocation.

Comment: @Stack-Boi please do not get depressed about making mistakes. *"The only man who never makes a mistake is the man who never does anything.* - Theodore Roosevelt

Comment: @Stack-Boi -- If you want to create a dynamic string, then you use `malloc`.  But does that go against you saying "you are not looking for a new solution"?  That's why my comment in the main thread states that to solve the problem dynamically, you *will* have to think about "new solutions".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will check out dynamic strings. When I said "_not looking for a new solution_", I meant a complete overhaul of my current solution. The purpose of me posting this question was to find out the mistake that I made, not get a new completely different solution (like the answer posted by Codesingh). You must be really fun at parties, huh?? :p

Comment: @Stack-Boi The issue is that many times, the simplest of code has holes in it that an overhaul sometimes is the only good solution.  Don't close your mind into thinking your code will work if you change a character here or there.  That's the way it sometimes works in this business.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior of [strcat](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) you are observing:

> The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both `src` and `dest` and the terminating null character.

So, before *appending* extra string to destination through `strcat`, make sure that the size of the destination is increased/adjusted accordingly such that :

```
destination_size >= strlen(dest)+strlen(src)+1
```

Another problem is that you are not getting the right width of spaces `' '` for each line. You would need nested `for` loop to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the answers with multiple loops, nested loops, complex logic, etc.

Formatting to `printf` is all you need in a single loop:
([IDEOne code](http://ideone.com/0MK9Pi))

*(This is pretty much your solution, but without the `strcat`, and just using a hard-coded string)*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int level = 6;
    for(int i=1; i<=level; ++i)
        printf("%*.*s\n", level, i, "#####################");

    return 0;
}
```

---

I fixed up your solution to use `memset` instead of `strcat`, and changed the for-loop slightly.

Personally, I still prefer a long constant string of `"###########"` over a `memset`-array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n,i; 
    char str[50];

    scanf("%d\n",&n);

    memset(str, '#', sizeof(str));

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%*.*s\n",n,i,str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `memset()` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: "_Personally, I still prefer a long constant string_". Isn't it more efficient to use memset() than have a very big string?

Comment: Efficient in what sense?  You may save a few bytes, but I don't think a hardcoded array of 50 characters is going to tax your computer, and I think it keeps the code a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Given five positive integers, find the minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. Then print the respective minimum and maximum values as a single line of two space-separated long integers.

Here is a C# solution:

```
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        string step = "";
        for (int k = 0; k < n - i; k++)
        {
            step += " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            step += "#";
        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(step);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void repeat (char input , int count ){
    for (int i=0; i != count; i++ ) {
        printf("%c", input);
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int temp1=1, temp=n-1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        repeat(' ',temp);
        repeat('#',temp1);
        temp--;
        temp1++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int n,i,j,k; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
    for(i=n-1;i>k;i--)
    {
      printf(" ");
    } 
    for(j=0;j<k+1;j++)
    printf("*");
    printf("\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP : I am not looking for a new solution.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
    if(i+j<=n-1)
    printf("#");
    else
    printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP said specifically: "I am **not looking for a new solution**."